# How to display ListView inside a Container without setting Container height in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

In my Flutter project, I show a list of data using ListView which is wrapped with Container. Now, when I am using the Container without setting it's height it shows the following error-

> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#a418c
> relayoutBoundary=up16 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1687
> pos 12: 'hasSize'

And here's the entire structure of the class I have written-

```
SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[

                showTheHistory(),

                Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-ScreenUtil.instance.setWidth(260),

                    child: Padding(
                      padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: ScreenUtil.instance.setWidth(10), right: ScreenUtil.instance.setWidth(10)),
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: FutureBuilder<List>(
                          future: _searchList,
                          initialData: List(),
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            return snapshot.hasData ?
                            new ListView.builder(
                              padding:  EdgeInsets.all(ScreenUtil.instance.setWidth(10)),
                              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                                return _buildRow(snapshot.data[i]);
                              },
                            )
                                : Center(
                              child: NoResultFoundScreen(),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                

                SizedBox(height: ScreenUtil.instance.setHeight(10),),

                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding:  EdgeInsets.only(left: ScreenUtil.instance.setWidth(10), right: ScreenUtil.instance.setWidth(10) ),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Card(
                          elevation: 6,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding:  EdgeInsets.all(ScreenUtil.instance.setWidth(5)),
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                
                                Text('English to ${Credentials.languageType}', style: TextStyle(fontSize: ScreenUtil.instance.setSp(18), color: Colors.teal, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)

                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),



                        Padding(
                          padding:  EdgeInsets.only(top:ScreenUtil.instance.setWidth(10)),
                          child: Card(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            elevation: 10,

                            child: Container(

                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[

                                  getHowToUseText('1. '),

                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:8.0, right: 8.0),
                                    child: Divider(height: 2, color: Colors.grey,),
                                  ),

                                  getHowToUseText('2. While typing you will get auto suggestions. You can tap on the words to see meaning'),

                                ],
                              ),
                            ),

                          ),
                        )


                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                SizedBox(
                  height: ScreenUtil.instance.setHeight(160),
                )

              ],
            ),
          ),
```

So, as you can see that these is a height set to the Container wrapping the ListView. In the ListView, the data takes time to load and in that period of time the Container with that fixed size remains blank which is visibly not good. So, I need a solution to make that Listview height dynamic in spite of setting the height of the Container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `shrinkWrap: true` property to the `listview` also remove the container .

Also you have so many redundant widgets. You should consider refactoring your codes. You should have a look at the widgets docs on flutter.dev

Comment: Thanks, it works. I am accepting your answer as correct but for enabling the the listview & SingleChildScrollView both scroll-
I just set  **physics: ScrollPhysics()**  to my ListView.builder.